# How to display data like Blogspot's BlogArchive in time order using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

How can I display data entry on my aspx page like Blogspot's BlogArchive in time order?

I think basically the database including a table with columns: Entry, Year, Month, Day so that we can display data like what I mean.
(check link: http://i160.photobucket.com/albums/t194/perakit/mess/BlogArchive.jpg)

Note: I use SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008, asp.net C# for my project.

Best thanks and appreciated for all replies.

Comment: Can you put up the code you used?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code in your `SqlDataSource`

```
SELECT Entry, Year, Month, Day
FROM EntryInfo 
ORDER BY Year, Month, Day;
```

Aspx Code (Client) :

```
<asp:SqlDataSource
      id="SqlDataSource1"
      runat="server"
      ConnectionString="...."
      SelectCommand="SELECT Entry, Year, Month, Day FROM EntryInfo ORDER BY Year, Month, Day;">
  </asp:SqlDataSource>

  <asp:GridView
      id="GridView1"
      runat="server"
      DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Displaying data by using Gridview does not like Blogspot's BlogArchive.
What I mean is below link:
http://i160.photobucket.com/albums/t194/perakit/mess/BlogArchive.jpg

Comment: I'am happy to help you user1767815